# How to get 1st-level comment from root element of xml

Tags: xml, go

my xsd file has following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- EIS docs-ws-api Integration Scheme, version 6.4, create date 15.11.2016 -->
<someTag></someTag>
```

how to get this comment?
i try did it on playground https://play.golang.org/p/PVHux_Gvb7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer, `xml.Unmarshal` can parse comment only if it's part of XML element.

External library [`xmlpath`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/xmlpath.v1) which implements [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) specification can be useful in your case.

> Install: `go get gopkg.in/xmlpath.v1`

Let's extract  `preceding` comment of tag named `someTag` from your example xml.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "strings"

    xmlpath "gopkg.in/xmlpath.v1"
)

func main() {
    data := `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- EIS docs-ws-api Integration Scheme, version 6.4, create date 15.11.2016 -->
<someTag></someTag>
`
    path := xmlpath.MustCompile("/someTag/preceding::comment()")
    root, err := xmlpath.Parse(strings.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if comment, ok := path.String(root); ok {
        fmt.Println(comment)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER** : The comment above is not in `root` element.It is outside of root element so `xml.Unmarshal` could not read it

**EXPLANATION**

> Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all
>   the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the
>   other elements. ROOT elements are also called document elements.

according to doc for [encoding/xml](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal)

> - If the XML element contains comments, they are accumulated in    the first struct field that has tag ",comment".  The struct    field may
>     have type []byte or string. If there is no such    field, the comments
>     are discarded.

Since the comment is outside all the elements.You may not decode it to a struct

An expanded example of an XML document follows, demonstrating rootElement element and headers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE example [<!ENTITY copy "&#xA9;">    
<rootElement attribute="xyz">
   <contentElement/>
</rootElement>
<!-- comment nodes may appear almost anywhere -->
```

Here is the Current(Jan-2017) standard for XML accroding to W3C : [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Comment)

Comment: @user2782106 please check the answer and accept if it solves the problem / addresses the problem correctly